# Accessing google sheet images onClick handle from another spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have created a masterspread sheet which acts as a template. When a new member signs a form, they are emailed the URL to their new sheet. Now this sheet has a backend to aid functionality. Two buttons (images) are contained within the sheet which have event links to functions in google script.
The problem lies with google script and the lack of ability to copy projects along with sheets.
For the creation of the new user sheets, I am currently using `SpreadsheetApp.OpenById('...').getSheetByName('...').CopyTo(newSheetDestination)`.

Basically, I'm trying to create multiple copies of a sheet but require the google apps script code to be copied with it.

I can't find any simple solution so does anyone have any ideas for a workaround? 
Would be much appreciated.

Comment: Copy the document, not the sheet.

Comment: Don't know how I didn't think of that! Many thanks pal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code

```
var Pid = <id of the parent spreadsheet>
var Sname = <give the name for the child>

var newDoc = DocsList
      .getFileById(Pid)
      .makeCopy(Sname);
```